# SQL Complex Conditional Aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the points of each team in the PL

I have two tables

**T1**

```
---------------------
TEAM ID || TEAM NAME
---------------------
01      || Liverpool
02      || Man City
---------------------
```

**while t2 for instance**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
MATCH ID || HOME TEAM || AWAY TEAM || HOME GOALS || AWAY GOALS|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
30       || Liverpool || Man City  || 1          || 0 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

To calculate the points
now for each match if a team has num of goals greater than the other team he won and he got 3 Points and the loser got 0 points
BUT if each one of them got the same num of goals they're even and each one of them got just 1 point.

**the new table should be like this**

```
-----------------------------------
Team ID || Team Name || Team Points
------------------------------------
01      || Liverpool || 28
02      || Man City  || 22
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your second table should be storing `TEAM ID` for `AWAY TEAM` and `HOME TEAM` instead of the team names so it could be easily joined to table 1.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't.

Look, I tried to break down t2 into two separate tables in the inner join (t2 H for host and t2 G for Guests) the point is :: is it possible to  make sum(case when H.HomeGoals> G.GuestGoals then 3 else 0) etc ..?? 

I'm afraid it's not right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.teamid, t1.teamname,
  sum(
    case sign((homegoals - awaygoals) * case when t1.teamname = t2.hometeam then 1 else -1 end)
      when 1 then 3
      when 0 then 1
      when -1 then 0
    end
  ) teampoints
from t1 inner join t2
on t1.teamname in (t2.hometeam, t2.awayteam)
group by t1.teamid, t1.teamname
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7UrdVxYTXWkpE9yqgAkXYq/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot forpas, for help and for your time. how clean. Such a great way of thinking

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: The condition in the `ON` clause is this: `on t1.teamname in (t2.hometeam, t2.awayteam)`, so there are 2 cases only: `t1.teamname = t2.hometeam` or `t1.teamname = t2.awayteam`. This: is why `case when t1.teamname = t2.hometeam then 1 else -1 end` check only 2 cases. This 1 or -1 is a factor multiplied to the difference of goals.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the explanation, forbas.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a lateral join:

```
select t1.team_id, t1.team_name, sum(v.goals),
       sum(case when goals > other_goals then 3 
                when goals = other_goals then 1
                else 0
           end) as points
from t2 cross join lateral
     (values (t2.home_team, t2.home_goals,  t2.away_goals),
             (t2.away_team, t2.away_goals, t2.home_goals)
     ) v(team, goals, other_goals) join
     t1
     on v.team = t1.team_id
group by t1.team_id, t1.team_name;
```

Comment: Such a wonderful solution Gordon, but how would you calculate the points?

Comment: @Nash . . . The same way.  It wasn't clear to me when I first read the question that "points" are different from "scores".

Comment: Such  a fascinating piece of code. but we don't need ``Sum (V. Goals)`` according to what the new table should be. yet, it's great work. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do join the table and do a conditional sum:

```
select
    t1.team_id,
    t1.team_name,
    sum(
        case 
            when t2.home_goals = t2.away_goals then 1
            when 
                ( t1.team_name = t2.home_team and t2.home_goals > t2.away_team)
                or (t1.team_name = t2.away_team and t2.away_goals > t2.home_team)
                then 3
            else 0 
        end
    ) team_points
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.team_name in (t2.home_team, t2.away_team)
group by t1.team_id, t1.team_name
```

In the `sum()`, the `case` expression checks the outcome of the game and assigns points as needed (3 points for a winning game, 1 point for a draw, 0 points for a loss).

Note: as it has been said in the comments, you should modifiy your schema to store the `id`s of the teams in the scores table instead of their names.

Comment: Thanks a lot GMB, for help and for your time.

Comment: But there's no goals in t1 !, I think you wanted to say `` When t2.home_goals = t2.guest_goals then 1`` right?

Comment: @Nash: you are correct. I just modified the query in my answer.

Comment: I think, you wanted to say, too: ``When(t1.team_name = t2.home_team and t2.home_goals > t2.away_goals), I mean the last column is for goals not name, Right?

Answer (score 0):

Now, what about this

```
SELECT t1.teamid,
        t1.teamname,
        SUM (CASE   WHEN    t1.teamname = t2.hometeam
                            AND     t2.homegoals > t2.awaygoals THEN    3
                    WHEN    t1.teamname =   t2.awayteam
                            AND     t2.homegoals < t2.awaygoals THEN    3
                    WHEN    t1.teamname IN (t2.hometeam, t2.awayteam)
                            AND     t2.homegoals = t2.awaygoals THEN    1
                    ELSE    0
                    END
             )AS    "Team Points"

FROM    t1
        INNER JOIN
        t2
        ON
        t1.teamname IN (t2.hometeam, t2.awayteam)

GROUP BY t1.teamid,
        t1.teamname
```

Here's the [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7UrdVxYTXWkpE9yqgAkXYq/3)